# Disk usage: How to only show max depth folders?

Tags: disk-space

I want to use the `du` command so I can find the folders on my system that are bigger than a certain size.

The problem with `du` are the results I get.

For example, I get all theses folders as results:

```
~/Downloads/MyFiles/MyPictures/Folder1/
~/Downloads/MyFiles/MyPictures/
~/Downloads/MyFiles/ 
~/Downloads/
```

When I only want to have :

```
~/Downloads/MyFiles/MyPictures/Folder1/
```

How can I do that with du or any other command?

Comment: So, you only count a folder if it has no sub folders or sub folders are ok if they are small? It’s not a direct answer, but `ncdu` or Daisy Disk  search rapidly / interactively once a map is done

Answer (score 1):

`du` alone won't help here, but you can combine `du` with `find` to accomplish this:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '(ls -p "{}" | grep -q /) || du "{}"' \;
```

What this does is the following:

- `find . -type d -exec ... \;` finds all directories and executes the part in `...` for each of them (with `{}` getting replaced by the path of the directory)
- `sh -c '...'` executes the `...` part in a subshell (because `-exec` only can execute a binary and doesn't itself know about shell syntax)
- `(ls -p "{}" | grep -q /)` lists all entries within the directory with a `/` appended if an entry itself is a directory, and then greps silently for lines containing `/`. We are only interested in the return code of `grep` here so if you want to manually check what it does run `(ls -p "DIR" | grep -q /); echo $?` with various DIRs to see the difference between directories containing sub-directories and directories which don't
- `|| du "{}"` gets executed only if the previous part (`(...)`) did *not* find any matches (meaning we are in a directory without further directories)

PS: Tip of the hat to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269798/use-gnu-find-to-show-only-the-leaf-directories for the essential details.

Comment: This is one to bookmark for advanced shell scripting. Well done, indeed!